# Spring integration components -Best practice

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration and am in  the process of getting a hold of the components. The requirement is as follows. Get an XML  message ,  validate the data using a web service call and  process the valid or invalid data accordingly. We currently use a router to  validate the data and  route the  original payload as per the validation result.  I have an  alternate  approach in mind to segregate this flow. I would like the router to perform only the routing job . For the web service validation , I am thinking of using a service activator . This in turn  will pass the routing information to the router -  could  be by using a header enricher. I have some questions here .  Is this the best practice? If so, how best can we pass the validation information received from the webservice to the router?.Also, will the addition of more  components not negate the advantages we get by component segregation? Please help.

Regards,
Aravind.

Comment: more components in spring integration eases separation of concerns/responsibilities, increases modularity and eases maintenance. More components actually equals component segregation. I wish I could have said that and meant it better 8 months ago. Will try to explain with POJO example later but have a look at some answers to my SI questions.. might help

Answer (score 2):

To help with a best practice approach consider a clear separation of responsibilities and what the validation is as a part of the flow.  For instance, you may consider the validation to actually be a filter, where only valid messages pass through and invalid are directed to a rejection channel.  The filter approach will work if you can distill the validation results toa boolean scenario.

(By the way, try to avoid extending Spring Integration classes/interfaces and instead create POJO services that you can reference.  Makes it easier to test and maintain)